# Unable to connect to HostGator (Shared Hosting) SQL DB from Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, shared-hosting

I'm trying to connect to the HostGator MSSQL Server database using the following connection string.

```
const string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;" +
         "Initial Catalog=mydb;" +
         "User id=my_user;" +
         "Password=my_password;";
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

I keep getting the following error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have tried the following variations for the data source.

```
localhost
127.0.0.1
.\SQLEXPRESS
```

Nothing works as intended. What could be the reason?

Comment: Any ideas which version and edition of SQL Server they're using? According to their [Windows Hosting](https://www.hostgator.com/windows-hosting) page they supply SQL Server 2008 R2 ... which lapsed out of extended support in 2019.

Comment: @techno Your connection string is incorrect. Could you please check it with your provider?

Comment: @MarkSpencer could you please let me know what is wrong.

Comment: @techno Please ask your provider about correct connection string. You can't use localhost anymore on your code.